# Sitecore.Context is null for custom admin pages outside admin folder in 9.3

Tags: admin-pages

I have a custom utility page in the 8.2 instance, placed at this location:

```
-website
|_sitecore
  |_minions
    |_mypage.aspx
```

In the `Page_Load`, there is only one method to check if user is logged in. If not, it will redirect to the login page.  This works fine.

Now, I have deployed the files to a 9.3 instance and the custom page never loads. It redirects to the login page.
On debug, `Sitecore.Context` is null & hence `Sitecore.Context.IsLoggedIn` is false.

[image]

When I move my page to the admin folder in 9.3, it works fine:

```
-mysite93
|_sitecore
  |_admin
    |_minions
     |_mypage.aspx
```

I'm logged in as admin in both instances.
Why does it work in 8.2 even when outside the admin folder but not in 9.3.
I want to keep my custom folder outside the `admin` folder and still make it work for 9.3. Is it possible. If yes, how.

Comment: I tried this in a vanilla Sitecore 9.3 instance and I didn't experience this behavior. I tried with both an existing admin page moved outside the `\sitecore\admin` folder and a new page under a custom folder. Do you have different authentication settings in IIS on your `minions` folder?

Comment: @AlessandroFaniuolo No special settings in IIS

Comment: @Qwerty are you using Glass Mapper if yes then have you checked that Glass service is initialized

Comment: @NikhilKulkarni. Not using glass mapper

Comment: @Qwerty - could you please try by changing the virtual, physical folder from "/sitecore/admin" to "/" for "admin" side in Sitecore.config? -`<site name="admin" virtualFolder="/sitecore/admin" physicalFolder="/sitecore/admin" enableTracking="false" enableWorkflow="true" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/sitecore/admin/login.aspx" />`

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible with the use of Identity Server at the /sitecore/ path is not included in one that is authenticated with IS?

Consider this file `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config` at the very end there is a section indicating which paths are authenticated.

```
<sites>
  <site name="shell" set:loginPage="$(loginPath)shell/SitecoreIdentityServer"/>
  <site name="admin" set:loginPage="$(loginPath)admin/SitecoreIdentityServer"/>
</sites>
```

Perhaps patching in a new entry for your custom path would make it work?